# Go Quorum Kubernetes Setup Node Replicas and Load Balancing

Tags: kubernetes, geth, quorum

Following the GoQuorum Official documentation, I was able to setup quorum nodes using Kubernetes and also bare metal raft setup with the help of the following links respectively [Qubernetes Setup](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/HowTo/GetStarted/Getting-Started-Qubernetes/) and [Raft Setup Bare Metal](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/Tutorials/Create-a-Raft-network/)

If I would like to have my quorum nodes deployed on Kubernetes Cluster, can I use the replica set feature effectively to replicate a quorum node for high availability? If not, on Kubernetes, what is the best way to maintain a replica of a node for Load balancing a high number of grpc requests? When I am trying to replicate it facing issues and my pod is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy a Raft-based application on Kubernetes, you want your instances to talk to the other instances.

In this case, you want "Stable, unique network identifiers." so that your instances effectively can address requests to the other instances using a known instance-address.

Deploy your app as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) to get this feature.